# How can I set Index on MongoDB replica set?

Tags: mongodb

When I try with normal indexing method like:

```
(db.collection.createIndex({'created_at':1},{'expireAfterSeconds':604800}))
```

That time command timeout and server crashed.

Can you please suggest the proper way?

Comment: That command should work.  Check the logs to see why the server crashed.

Comment: Try to build index in background if you've huge data.